# Text following a JqueryUI button is set as the button title

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I have the following code:

```
$( ".delete" ).button({
text: false,
icons: {
primary: "ui-icon-trash"
}
});

<button id="delete" class="delete" />test
```

The word "test" is being appended to the button as its title, for some reason, instead of appearing after the button.  If text is set to false, the button shows with only an icon.  If text is not set to false, the word "test" appears within the button.  It should just be some text following the button, and I can find no reason as to why the button is nabbing it for a title.  I've also tried defining a title, a label...hasn't helped.  Thanks.

Comment: is the missing `});` just a typo/paste error??

Comment: Yes.  I'll add that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing your markup as such should resolve this:

```
<button id="delete" class="delete" ></button>test
```

Comment: Ah, no self-closing tags here, I guess.  Thank you.